# Writing columns of a matrix as linear combinations of other columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let A be the matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&2&1&0\\2&4&5&3&3&1\\1&2&2&1&2&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

What is the best way to write the fifth and sixth columns of the matrix as linear combinations of the first and third columns?

Answer (score 3):

First consider column 5

We can think of it as

\begin{align}a\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\2\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\2\end{pmatrix}\\
&\Downarrow \\
a+3b&=1\\
2a+5b&=3\\
a+2b&=2
\end{align}

So $a=1-3b$

Therefore \begin{align}2(1-3b)+5b&=3\\
2-6b+5b&=3\\
2-3&=b\\
b&=-1
\end{align}

And so $a=1-(3\times-1)=4$

So we have \begin{align}4\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\2\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}4\\8\\4\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\2\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\2\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

---

We can then do this again for column 6

\begin{align}c\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}+d\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\2\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\\
&\Downarrow \\
c+3d&=0\\
2c+5d&=1\\
c+2d&=1\end{align}

So we have $c=-3d$

Therefore we have \begin{align}2(-3d)+5d&=1\\
-6d+5d&=1\\
-d&=1\\
d&=-1
\end{align}

And so $c=-3d= -3\times -1 = 3$

And so we have \begin{align}3\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\2\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}3\\6\\3\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\2\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

In principle, you need to solve a series of linear equations, as described in detail in [lioness99a’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2186453/265466). It’s possible to do this “in bulk.” Recall that one way to solve such an equation is to create an augmented matrix and row-reduce it. You can in fact package *all* of the vectors into a single matrix and solve all of the equations at once via row-reduction.

In this case, we’d put the first and third columns on the left-hand side, and the fifth and sixth on the right: $$\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}1&3 & 1&0 \\ 2&5 & 3&1 \\ 1&2 & 2&1\end{array}\right)$$ and row-reduce to get $$\left(\begin{array}{cc|rr}1&0 & 4&3 \\ 0&1 & -1&-1 \\ 0&0 & 0&0\end{array}\right).$$ The required coefficients appear in the first two rows of the columns on the right. If a column *can’t* be written as a linear combination of the ones on the left, then the corresponding column of the reduced matrix will have a non-zero entry in at least one of the other rows. This also gives you a way to check that the first and third columns are in fact linearly independent. If not, there won’t be a pivot in the second column of the reduced matrix.